# How to stop 3rd party libraries from being reported as malicious, if they were part of malicious programs in the past?

Tags: antivirus, antimalware, software, code-signing, driver

Some are standard user space dll’s and another one is actually a windows driver. The libraries alone are not dangerous and are pure utilities but they can be used by bad guys, like most software tools.

I was advised to sign the driver with my own certificate, but would that not only hurt my own certificates reputation by association? I think kernel drivers are nowadays only signed through Dev Portal but it would still contain my certificate.

If I sign it and somehow manage to get it white-listed for my use case, a malicious actor could then steal the library from my installed program and use it in his malware without me even knowing.

I am unsure if recompiling would help in any ways as well. Seems unlikely. I wish to avoid that so I do not make any mistakes that would be disastrous for system stability. A complete rewrite is beyond the scope of my skills.

Comment: On Windows 10 after about 2016, kernel drivers need to be signed by Microsoft. See: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/kernel-mode-code-signing-policy--windows-vista-and-later-#signing-requirements-by-version

Comment: What libraries are being reported? You say "standard" DLLs, but what does that mean? You mean stock Microsoft Windows DLLs? Or what?

Comment: 3rd party libraries that are wide-spread, part of several other big projects and are often already digitally signed by their developers.